# Double results MYSQL query (Drupal database)

Tags: mysql, join, double

I'm trying to get a SQL result where I want to join some fields to users (from a Drupal database). My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_wekelijkse_newsletter ON users.uid = field_data_field_wekelijkse_newsletter.entity_id 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_woonplaats ON users.uid = field_data_field_woonplaats.entity_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_naam ON users.uid = field_data_field_naam.entity_id
```

I have two problems:

1. I get double results (usernames)
2. The values for "field_data_field_wekelijkse_newsletter" are different within the double results.

Can someone help me write a good query?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about your data model, and only going off the naming of the columns, it is possible that your results are not duplicates after all. If users can subscribe to more than one newsletter, than perhaps that is what is happening. You are returning all of the fields from **every** table that you `JOIN` on. If you provide more information such as schema definitions, column names, etcetera, I can give a much more precise answer.

In addition, I can offer you a few styling tips in regards to writing SQL!

1. Use newlines and tabs, write your queries for the developer coming in behind you! Readable queriers are the best (and usually bug free) queries.
2. Use **aliases**. Typically, I treat aliases very similar to variable names: I keep them **meaningful** and **short**. If you cannot create a meaningful, short alias for the table, then use the table's initials (for table names such as *field_data_field_woonplaats*, it is difficult to create a simple alias! Consider renaming)
3. Nomenclature is everything! Name your tables, columns, views, indexes, triggers, keys, everything, simply so that you (and other developers) can remember them easily and are able to grasp and fully understand what kind of object they represent (the data they hold).
4. Use semicolons to terminate statements.

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM users u
   LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_wekelijkse_newsletter  fdfwn
    ON u.uid = fdfwn.entity_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_woonplaats fdfw 
    ON u.uid = fdfwn.entity_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_naam fdfn
    ON u.uid = fdfn.entity_id;
   ```